Danskins' theorem in functional space
The standard Danskin's theorem says that (Taken from wikipedia):
Suppose $\phi (x,z)$ is a continuous function of two arguments,
$$\phi :{\mathbb {R} }^{n}\times Z\rightarrow {\mathbb {R} }$$
where
$Z\subset {\mathbb {R} }^{m}$
is a compact set. Further assume that
$ \phi (x,z)$
is convex in $x$ for every $z\in Z$.
Define
$$f(x)=\max _{z\in Z}\phi (x,z)$$
and
$$Z_{0}(x)=\left\{{\overline {z}}:\phi (x,{\overline {z}})=\max _{z\in Z}\phi (x,z)\right\}.$$
Danskin's theorem: if $\phi (\cdot,z)$ is differentiable for all $z \in Z$ and $ \triangledown_x \phi (x,\cdot)$ is continuous on Z for each x, then the sub-differential (i.e., set of sub-gradients) of $f(x)$, denoted by $\partial f(x)$, is given by
$$\partial f(x) = \text{conv}\left\{ \triangledown_x \phi (x,z) \mid z \in Z_0(x) \right\}$$
where ${\text{conv} }$ indicates the convex hull operation.
My question: To what extent can the assumption that $Z\subset {\mathbb {R} }^{m}$ be relaxed? If the set $Z$ is a compact set in a general metric space (e.g., set of uniformly bounded functions on interval $[0,1]$), does Danskin's theorem still hold？

There is this nice paper „envelope theorems for arbitrary choice sets“ by Milgrom, where some generalizations are treated. Maybe it contains a version of the Theorem that suits your purpose.

@HyperbolicPDEfriend Yeah, I am familiar with this paper. Envelop theorem and Danskins' theorem indeed look very related. In Milgrom's paper, $X \in \mathbb{R}$, (though it seems easy to extend to general $R^m$). Also, Milgrom's paper indicates what are the sub-gradients but does not provide the sub-differential (i.e., set of all sub-gradients). These are my understanding..

@HyperbolicPDEfriend Envelop theorem is more general though (in some aspect), because it does not require convexity.

Where does it say that $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$?

And maybe you know this and this paper.

@HyperbolicPDEfriend Please see footnote 7 in Milgrom's paper (their t is my x here). And I will check these two papers. Thank you for pointing out to me!

Theorem 9.26 of this text: https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/1.9781611976595
talks about sufficient conditions when the set is replaced by a compact set of a general topological space.

@ztwang Thank you so much!! This is exactly what I'm looking for!!
